# Виртуальные и не очень машины и сети

Tags: сеть, виртуализация

В общем ситуация у меня интересная получилась: решил поднять на виртуалке небольшую сеть. Теперь вопрос в том, как соединить систему с интернетом.

**Минусы.**

- В сети ни фига нет DHCP (вот такая дрянная сеть на хабах).
- Одни статические адреса, так что получить автоматом настройки не
  выйдет.
- Структура сети будет достаточно неоднородная и разнотипная (БСД/Линупсы/ВинСервер/Солярка(возможно)).
- Плюсом еще будет софтверный роутер и НАТ. Более подробно смотрите картинку.

**Плюс.**

Статический айпишник всегда на хост-машине, и на ней хотя бы доступ настроен в инет.

Нужно руководство по маршрутизации статической и как пробросить соединения, скажем, от конечной машины до работающего инета. На данный момент есть только возможность пинговать "удаленные" гостевые машины, находясь в хост-машине, проходя через софт-роутер. Иначе говоря, связь есть, но только по локальной сети между машинками. В реальную (большую) локальную сеть пока пробиться не получается. Картинка-план, как все это будет выглядеть прилагается.[image]

Comment: А на чем крутиться роутер и НАТ будет? Немного не понимаю из вашей картинки, почему конечные хосты (как я понял внизу картинки) объединены через роутер (вам же между ними не нужна маршрутизация)?

Comment: Роутер-софтверный.НАТ и форвардинг будет на реальной машине настроен.Цель-достучаться до инета с виртуальных рабочих станций.Пока только есть сооединения между всеми виртуалками(5 серверных систем),роутером,и рабочей станицией.На уровне пингов и ssh-доступа.Осталось прикрутить доступ в инет с виртуалок.

Answer (score 1):

В общем мой случай (да и любой аналогичный, по-моему, будет решаться так). На хост машине настраиваем НАТ и форвадинг.

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j SNAT --to-source y.y.y.y
```

Настраиваем замену для eth0 (мой статический адрес x.x.x.x) и ppp0 (адрес, испольуемый для выхода в инет от провайдера с использование VPN и наших технологий сети).

```
#echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter#echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Включаем форвадинг.

Если есть софтовый роутер, как у меня, на нем тоже небольшие манипуляции с натом, чтоб он прокидывал пакеты как от источника.

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x
```

Через eth0 софтовый роутер смотрит в инет (ну ему кажется, что в инет, на самом деле он смотрит на вирутуальный адаптер).

+ надо еще повоевать с маршрутаризацией между всеми хостами (вирутуальными, локальными, сетями).

Но в итоге я победил все это и сейчас начинаю обновлять софт на всех 5-ти вирутальных машинках.